# Counting the amount of letters in all permutations of words in R

Tags: r, permutation, counting

I have some words:

```
shapes<- c("Square", "Triangle","Octagon","Hexagon")
```

I want to arrange them in pairs:

```
shapescount<-combn(shapes, 2)

shapescount

[,1]       [,2]      [,3]      [,4]       [,5]       [,6]     
[1,] "Square"   "Square"  "Square"  "Triangle" "Triangle" "Octagon"
[2,] "Triangle" "Octagon" "Hexagon" "Octagon"  "Hexagon"  "Hexagon"
```

I want to count each of the groupings of the letters in the pairs, for instance first pair is "6" for "Square" and "8" for "Triangle" giving me "14" for the first pair, and so on.

Comment: have you tried `nchar`

Comment: Have you double checked how many letters are in "Triangle"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way:

```
colSums(combn(shapes, 2, FUN=nchar))
# [1] 14 13 13 15 15 14
```

Benchmarks:

```
shapes <- rep(c("Square", "Triangle","Octagon","Hexagon"), 50)
matthew <- function() colSums(combn(shapes, 2, FUN=nchar))
ananda <- function() combn(shapes, 2, FUN=function(x) sum(nchar(x)))
tstenner <- function() {
    shapelengths <- nchar(shapes)
    colSums(combn(shapelengths, 2))
}
microbenchmark(matthew(), ananda(), tstenner())
# Unit: milliseconds
#        expr   min    lq median    uq    max neval
#   matthew() 53.27 55.84  56.37 57.04  98.83   100
#    ananda() 74.74 78.42  79.88 80.60 123.29   100
#  tstenner() 29.27 31.03  31.52 33.44  76.01   100
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `apply` and `nchar`:

```
> apply(shapescount, 2, function(x) sum(nchar(x)))
[1] 14 13 13 15 15 14
```

Since `combn` also has a `FUN` argument, you can do it all in one go:

```
> combn(shapes, 2, FUN=function(x) sum(nchar(x)))
[1] 14 13 13 15 15 14
```

Comment: even better!   very nice

Comment: @SimonO101 I'll recover! looks like tstenner is the most efficient, however.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde I missed that. `combn` with `integer` over `character` I guess. +1 duly awarded!

Answer (score 4):

You're likely looking for `nchar`.

To make things faster, don't compute all permutations of strings but of string lengths:

```
shapes<- c("Square", "Triangle","Octagon","Hexagon")
shapelengths <- nchar(shapes)
colSums(combn(shapelengths, 2))
```

If you're looking for one expression, simply inline the call to `nchar()`:

```
colSums(combn(nchar(shapes), 2))
```